# Displaying image when mouse clicked?

Tags: java, image, swing

So I'm a very new programmer and I watched a youtube tutorial on how to make a mouse listener. I'm still very fuzzy on what a mouse listener is but where my code currently stands (I mostly just copied it from the video), the background starts out white and when the mouse is released, the background changes to red.

What I actually want to do is display an image, and when the mouse is released, display a different image.

How do I do that?

Here's my current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;


public class switchScreens extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mousepanel;
    private JLabel statusbar;

    public switchScreens(){
        super("title");

        mousepanel = new JPanel();
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(mousepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
        mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);
    }
        private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
                mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
            }       
    }

}
```

Update: My new code; the background doesn't change at all when clicked

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class switchScreens extends JFrame{

    private JLabel mousetest;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Untitled.png");

    public switchScreens(){

        mousetest = new JLabel();
        add(mousetest, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
        mousetest.addMouseListener(handler);
    }
        private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
                mousetest.setIcon(icon);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
            }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You state that:

> - the background starts out white and when the mouse is released, the background changes to red.
> - What I actually want to do is display an image, and when the mouse is released, display a different image.

And you show this code:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

---

So you know how to use a MouseListener and where the code should go to make your change, and so the solution to your problem is sort of simple -- instead of `mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);` put in code to change the image. But the all important specifics of how to do this will depend on details of your problem, details that you've not told us or shown us. Specifics such as what image? Where to display it? At the site of the mouseReleased? Do you know how to display any image yet?

---

**Edit**
So again, what are the details of your problem?

- Unless you have multiple images and they're large, you'll likely want to read them into variables before rendering the GUI, perhaps in your class's constructor. I usually read my Images in using the `ImageIO.read(...)` method.
- If your goal is to give the GUI a background image on mouseReleased, then one way is to put a JLabel into your JFrame, convert the Image into an ImageIcon, and then call the JLabel variable's `setIcon(myIcon)` on mouseReleased, passing the ImageIcon you created into the method call.
- If your goal is something else entirely, then you'll again need to tell us the details.

Comment: Well I just copied the code from the youtube video so no, I don't really understand it. can I put an image link where i have "Color.RED"?

Comment: @user3696172: you shouldn't blindly copy code for this very reason. You still haven't told the details of your problem. Are you trying to draw a small image at the mouse location? Change a background image? What? These details are **very** important. As to substituting an "image link" whatever that means, then no. You will want to check the Java API for the `setBackground(...)` method, since if you did, you will see that it accepts a Color parameter and that's it.

Comment: @user3696172: I've edited my answer to provide more details. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm trying to change a background image.

Comment: @user3696172: thanks for the information, then my edited answer applies. Why not give it a try -- add a JLabel to your JFrame instead of the JPanel mousepanel, add the MouseListener to the JLabel, and then in the MouseListener call the label's `setIcon(ImageIcon icon)` method. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, how do I use the setIcon method? How do i make my image into an icon? don't really know what an icon is, again I'm a beginner

Comment: @user3696172: you will want to Google some tutorials as we don't have the ability to lead you by the hand through everything. You must show a little initiative here. Google the `Java JLabel Tutorial` to start with. Then if still stuck, please show us your code attempts to do this and the details of any problems with your code attempts. Good luck!

Comment: well, just fyi this is for fun and not for school or anything...but I updated the code following your input and still no background image is displayed...can you point me in the right direction? thanks!

Comment: @user3696172: great! That is how I learned coding too, on my own. So keep at it, but please do use the resources available to you to their maximum, especially the [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) and the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). For Swing specific issues, check out [these resources](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: I figured it out, anyway :D it works only when I type out the full file path, for some reason

Comment: This means that your image file path was originally not correct. Understand that Java looks for any files starting from the user directory, and this can be found by placing `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` somewhere in your program.

Comment: that worked for me and solved a couple problems i'd had earlier on something else, too...thanks again!